# Using Find functions to paste the found Entire Row

Tags: excel, vba, find, resize

I am trying to use a Find function to find the value of the Active cell in Sheet 2 (I force the active cell to be selected in column A, so if I select "B4", the active cell is "A4").
I would like the Find function to find the value of the "A" active cell from Sheet 2 and find it in Sheet 1, then paste the entire row of the that found row from Sheet 1 into row 2 of Sheet 2.

To break it down:

- Find the value of Sheet 2 column "A" active cell inside of column A in Sheet 1
- Copy the entire row into Sheet 2 row 2 of the found column A in sheet 1

I am receiving the following error:
`Run-time error 1004: "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' Failed` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference

I tried to use a variety of combinations to do this, here is a snapshot of my attempts:

```
Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(Sheet2.Range("ActiveCell"), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value
        'Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value
        
        'Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(90).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range(Target.Value), , xlValues, xlWhole).Resize(90).Value
        
        'Sheet2.Rows(2).EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(Sheet2.Range("ActiveCell"), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value
       
       'Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range(ActiveCell), , xlValues, xlWhole).Resize(90).Value
       'Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(90).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range(ActiveCell), , xlValues, xlWhole).Resize(90).Value
```

Below is the entire code, between where the code is commented `Testing below` & `Testing Above` is where my attempts are:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    If Target.Row > 2 Then                                                                      'Doesn't Allow the "Titles" in Row 1 to be highlighted or changed

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        'ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))   'Defines the name of the ActiveCell as "MyRange" to Autofill VLookup Formula on sheet
        
        Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select                                                    'Always Selects Column A depending on the Active Row selecte

        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0                       'Clears the previous Active Row's interior colour (yellow)

        Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(243, 243, 123)                                    'Sets the current Active Row's interior colour (as yellow)

'Testing below

        Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(Sheet2.Range("ActiveCell"), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value
        'Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value
        
        'Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(90).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range(Target.Value), , xlValues, xlWhole).Resize(90).Value
        
        'Sheet2.Rows(2).EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(Sheet2.Range("ActiveCell"), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value
       
       'Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range(ActiveCell), , xlValues, xlWhole).Resize(90).Value
       'Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(90).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range(ActiveCell), , xlValues, xlWhole).Resize(90).Value
        
'Testing above
        
        If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then                                                         'Checks if you have selected Row 2 (The comparison row)

            Target.Value = ""                                                                   'If Cell A2 is selected (the "Key" comparison cell from the comparison row) then a blank value is inputted

        Else                                                                                    'If Cell A2 is not selected

            [a2] = ActiveCell                                                                   'Makes cell "A2" equal to the Active Cell value (The "Key" in this case)

        End If                                                                                  'End IF statement

        Me.Range("B2:CK2").Interior.Color = xlNone                                              'Clears any previous (if any) colouring inside cells

        Dim rng As Range                                                                        'Declares variable as a range to store values

        For Each rng In Me.Range("D2:CK2")                                                      'Declares which columns to highlight yellow if there are any parameters in Sheet 2 that vary from Sheet 1

            If IsNumeric(rng.Value) And IsNumeric(Me.Cells(Target.Row, rng.Column)) Then        '[Exludes the Key, Date, Time & Part columns: hence starting at Column D for highlighting variances]

                If rng.Value <> Me.Cells(Target.Row, rng.Column).Value Then                     'Checks if the parameters vary from the main Database ("HE 171")

                    rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow                                               'Highlights any varying parameters in Yellow

                End If                                                                          'End the first IF statement

            End If                                                                              'End the second IF statement

        Next                                                                                    'Compares the next parameter until it reaches the last parameter

    End If                                                                                      'End the initial IF statement at the beginning of the macro

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That blanket `On Error Resume Next` is just hiding potential errors, best to remove that.

Comment: I forgot to remove that from a previous test I was doing, thanks for catching that Ben! I am now receiving a ```Run-time error 1004: "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' Failed``` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference

Comment: `Sheet2.Range("ActiveCell")` makes no sense. You would have to have a range named "ActiveCell" for that to work.

Comment: how about my second attempt, ```Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value```

Comment: What do you expect `"A" & ActiveCell` to return? That is implicitly `"A" & ActiveCell.Value`...which is probably not a valid `Range` reference.

Comment: @BigBen I was trying to get it to find the value inside of Column A in the active row for the Find function (but I already use ```Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select``` to select column A with respect to the ActiveRow selected

Comment: `"A" & ActiveCell.Row` is a valid range reference.... `"A" & ActiveCell` is very different.

Comment: ```Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value``` seems to work now! as I replaced ```"A" & ActiveCell``` with ```"A" & ActiveCell.Row``` Please post this as an answer so I can give credit where it's due, thanks Ben

Comment: @BigBen Also on a side note, is there any way to slightly slow up my code that you can see?

Comment: Posted an answer. Did you mean "speed up" instead of "slow up"?

Comment: @BigBen wow haha yes I meant "speed up"

Comment: Value transfer, i.e. `Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = foundRange.EntireRow.Value`, is fast... much better than using `Copy/Paste`. I'm not sure exactly what you're doing though in general, i.e. how is it slow.

Comment: I tested it and the value transfer is really slowing it down, I currently have ```If Not Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

        Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value
    
    Else

        Sheet2.Rows(2).EntireRow.ClearContents

    End If```

Comment: Value transfer is normally fast. I don't know if it would improve it but one option would be to find the last column instead of copying the *entire* row... which is 16384 columns.

Comment: @BigBen Using your suggestion, is this what you meant? ```If Not Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
      
        Dim foundrange As Long
        foundrange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100000").Find(Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = foundrange.EntireRow.Value
        
    Else
    
         Sheet2.Rows(2).EntireRow.ClearContents

    End If```

Comment: `Dim foundRange As Range` first of all. Do the `Find` first, then test `If Not foundRange Is Nothing`.

Comment: @BigBen oh right as a range whoops, that seems to work a little faster, thanks again Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(Sheet2.Range("ActiveCell"), , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireRow.Value
```

This is problematic for at least two reasons:

- `Sheet2.Range("ActiveCell")` would only work if there were a range named `ActiveCell` on `Sheet2`.
- If the `.Find` fails (i.e. if it doesn't find the value in question), then this will throw an error.

To fix:

- Change to `Sheet2.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)`.
- Test if the `Find` succeeded, before doing anything else, like the following:

```vb
Dim foundRange as Range
Set foundRange = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(Sheet2.Range("ActiveCell"), , xlValues, xlWhole)

If Not foundRange is Nothing Then
    Sheet2.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = foundRange.EntireRow.Value
End If
```